# When archaeology says "a 12th century structure", does it mean the structure EXISTED till 12th century or it was BUILT in 12th century?

Tags: archaeology

When archaeological study says "a 12th century structure", does it mean they found a structure in the 12th century "layer"? If a structure was built in 12th century and existed till 15th century, will it be treated as a 12th century structure or 15th century structure?

A mosque was demolished in 1992 and archaeological study was done on the site. They said "a 12th century temple" was found. Mosque inscriptions say it was built in 1528. Now does that mean it was possibly built after demolishing the 12th century temple? Or does it mean the temple did not even exist in 1528?
And how is a demolished/ruined/buried structure dated compared to a structure which is still standing (for ex; like the Leaning tower of Pisa?

Excerpt from [Archaeology of Ayodhya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaeology_of_Ayodhya):

> ### Archaeological layers
>
> ASI mentioned in its report that they have found ruins of other eras also. These ruins could be the ruins of a Jain temples.
>
> - 1000BCE to 300BCE: the findings suggest that a Northern Black Polished Ware (NBPW) culture existed at the mosque site between 1000 BCE and 300 BCE. A round signet with a legend in Ashokan Brahmi, terracotta figurines of female deities with archaic features, beads of terracotta and glass, wheels and fragments of votive tanks have been found.
> - Shunga Period. 200 BC: Typical terracotta mother goddess, human and animal figurines, beads, hairpins, pottery (includes black slipped, red and grey wares), and stone and brick structures of the Shunga period have been found.
> - Kushan period. 100–300 CE: terracotta human and animal figurines, fragments of votive tanks, beads, bangle fragments, ceramics with red ware and large-sized structures running into twenty-two courses have been found from this level.
> - Gupta era (320–600 CE) and post-Gupta era: typical terracotta figurines, a copper coin with the legend Sri Chandra (Gupta), and illustrative potsherds of the Gupta period have been found. A circular brick shrine with an entrance from the east and a provision for a water-chute on the northern wall have also been found.
> - 11th to 12th century CE: a huge structure of almost fifty metres in north–south orientation have been found on this level. Only four of the fifty pillar bases belong to this level. Above this lay a structure with at least three structural phases which had a huge pillared hall.

Comment: I would be more comfortable if this were phrased more specifically.  This appears to be a statement about a specific statement in a specific, uncited archaeology study, not a question about standards and practice in archaeology in general.   I'm concerned about an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I don't see any mention of a 12th century temple in the image, or in the associated Wikipedia page.  Also please note that the ASI study has been challenged, _*and*_ that this site is highly politically contentious.  It may not be possible to separate history from modern politics. Recommend you revise to avoid "push question"

Comment: "Does it mean the structure existed till the 12th century?" If that were so, all buildings which are still standing would be described as 21st century buildings!

Comment: Would this not better suit English Language Leaners?

Why would you doubt that archaeologically, 'a 12th century structure' could mean anything but a structure built in the 12th century?

Answer (score 16):

This usually means "built in the twelfth century." However, the means of dating are significant here. News reports usually omit that vital detail, and it's necessary to look for more solid information. Possible means of dating include:

- Architectural style. These can be quite revealing, but it depends on how quickly the style changed, and how quickly the change spread from region to region.
- Historical records, dates on the building, and suchlike. These are useful, but if they're from a long time ago, the calendar has to be translated, and the records aren't always accurate.
- Contextual clues. If there are remains of a temple underneath remains of a mosque that was built in 1582, than the temple was presumably there before the mosque. But that's a case where politics might well be involved, so checking what the archaeologists really said is important, as well as considering their possible biases.

History is often difficult to do well. That's why it is a scientific discipline, with a lot of methods to follow, and significant caveats in its results.

Comment: Finding remains of X underneath remains of Y should not lead to a presumption that X was demolished to build Y: for example Londonderry was built in 1613 on the site of Derry (paid for by London companies - hence the longer name), but the then relatively new city of Derry had been burnt in 1608 in a rebellion rather than in preparation for rebuilding.

Comment: @JohnDallman Could you please take a look at the image attached and share your thoughts? What does "Archaeological Layers" indicate here? Do they correspond to layers in the ground?

Comment: @Anonymous: I am not skilled in practical archaeology, and I'm not touching that mosque/temple conflict.